# Как вставить данные из 2 связанных таблиц чтобы сохранилось их связь через ID (PK, FK)

Tags: sql, база-данных, firebird

Есть главная таблица Producers и подчиненная Goods.

```
***************   
***Producers***
***************
producer_id prmary key,
Producer_Name


************
***Goods****
************
Id Primary key,
producer_id Foreign key,
Good_Name
```

С помощью IBEXPERT вытащил данные из Producer но когда скрипт вставит в новую таблицу их связь потеряется. Если, например, в Producer ест такие данные:

```
PRODUCER_ID PRODUCER_name 
41           AAA
42           BBB
43           CCC
```

после вставки данных sql-скриптом в таблице PRODUCERS новой бд

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCER (PRODUCER_ID, PRODUCER_name) VALUES (41, 'AAA');
```

генератор  присваивает производителю 'AAA' ID вместо 41 новое значение 1, 'BBB'-ID 2, 'CCC'- ID 3 и т.д., а в подчиненной таблице правильно присваивается 41,42,43. т.е. целостность данных нарушается?! (см. скрин).

Как в IBEXPERT вытащить данные из обойх таблиц так чтобы не потерять их связь через Producer_id?

**UPDATE:**
Когда включил галочку "Extract All" и читает все данные  из обоих таблиц потом всё  правильно вставляет в новых таблицах, ID главной таблицы правильно сохраняется(41-ый ID для "AAA".42-ой для "BBB" и т.д. или как на скрине, 50-ый ID правильно присваивается "222"). Как, не могу понять!

Ведь в первую очередь создаются новые домены и генераторы, потом таблицы, потом вставляет записи, потом создаются внешние ключи и потом создаются триггеры. Пока записи вставляется и потом заработают триггеры?! Как и на каком этапе обеспечивается целостность данных? Если одинокая таблица тогда генератор игнорирует мой ID и инкрементирует последный ID,  а если связанные таблицы тогда...?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прочитай про автоинкремент и примерикей пару примеров сам поймешь, внешний ключ FK обеспечивает целостность данных

Comment: Если Вы пишете "присвоить PRODUCER_ID значение 41", то либо оно будет присвоено, либо будет ошибка. А присвоение вместо заданного значения некоего автогенерированного - это либо самодеятельность использованного клиента, либо сказка.

Comment: Akina, смотрите пожалуйста скрин

Comment: Триггер покажи. Думаю там что-то вроде `new.PRODUCER_ID=gen_id(GENERATOR_NAME,1);`

Comment: А надо `if (new.PRODUCER_ID is null) then new.PRODUCER_ID=...`